# How to make `jekyll serve --watch` list which file is regenerated?

Tags: jekyll

I'm having an issues where `jekyll serve` gets caught in an infinite loop when a file is changed. To debug this, I want to know which file is causing the regeneration, listed in the `Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at ...` output.

For example, here is my output:

```
[my-pc]/home/.../websites/openseattle.github.io$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /home/lucas/projects/websites/openseattle.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /home/lucas/projects/websites/openseattle.github.io
       Destination: /home/lucas/projects/websites/openseattle.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.616 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/lucas/projects/websites/openseattle.github.io'
Configuration file: /home/lucas/projects/websites/openseattle.github.io/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
      Regenerating: 2 file(s) changed at 2017-06-04 19:40:58 ...done in 0.485150987 seconds.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-06-04 19:40:59 ...done in 0.45860538 seconds.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-06-04 19:41:00 ...done in 0.482768408 seconds.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-06-04 19:41:00 ...done in 0.46793245 seconds.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-06-04 19:41:01 ...done in 0.466628054 seconds.
```

how do I know which file has triggered the regeneration?

Comment: currently it's not possible out-of-the-box to debug which file triggers the regeneration. If you're familiar with Ruby and comfortable with editing gems, I have a [patch](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-watch/pull/42/files) at the `jekyll-watch` repo that'll point out which file(s) exactly trigger the regen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, but I wish there was an easier way (as mentioned by @ashmaroli in the comment above):

Run `bundle show jekyll-watch` to find out where your `jekyll-watch` module is located.

You should find a file named `watcher.rb`. It should look like this: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-watch/blob/master/lib/jekyll/watcher.rb#L56

Then add a print or debugger statement on line 55-56 to get information about the file that is causing the generation.